# batch file copy program to prompt user for source and destination paths

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-vista

I need to know how to program a batch file to prompt user for source and destination paths.
Once paths are entered by the user, the application will copy all files/folders
from [SOURCE] to [DESTINATION]

- The solution should not require any user input beyond source and destination paths
- It should use a system of variables to contain the paths
- It should log copy process

So far i have :

```
    xcopy "c:\source" "c:\destination" /e /h /k /o
    pause
```

Comment: [See this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php).

Comment: @RobertAllan what code would i use?

Answer (score 1):

Set command can take input from user: `set /p source=Enter Source path`.

Read help (`set /?`) for more information.

```
set /p source=Enter Source path
xcopy %source% "c:\destination" /e /h /k /o
```

Comment: how could i program this to prompt user for source and destination input, then once user enters the input for both source and destination files are copied from source to destination?